# How to proceed with these types of project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, linq-to-sql, wcf-rest

I am going lead a project, where I have Asp.Net webapp with SQL Server 2008 database and a WCF Service with REST to expose the data of the database to clients like winform app, java apps, android apps etc.

I want to use LINQ to Sql in my project. Earlier i have experience over the n layered architecture. Please help. How to take steps?

I have 4 different projects in a single solution. Should I need to divide it parts like WebApp with Sql Server database in a single project, Service and Client in two differents projects, as we might deploy our WCF service in some other server...

**See update

**to make it more clear , my project has three main aspects, a web app, service and client app. WebApp will be hosted on someserver. On the same server, i would like to deploy the service. Webapp has nothing to do with the service. It will directly interact with the database. On the other hand, the service has permission for selecting records from the database, not Insert, delete and update. Client app will be scattered to different location. It might be a winapp, wince app ,android app or java app. and it will interact with the service to fetch data only. Thats my plan.****

Comment: Ask your project manager about this.

Comment: I have started my own group with 4-5 team mates, i am the dev, Lead, project manager, CTO, CEO, and whatever you can say.

Comment: Why LINQ to SQL? Why not the Entity Framework?

Comment: @Morten Frederiksen : Its a personal choice. I found L2S ez to understand and implement as compared to Entity Framework. Anyways any strong reason to support your answer.. why EF why notL2S?

Comment: LINQ to SQL can only map directly to the database tables and only supports SQL Server. Entity Framework is mroe flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your asking about how to architect a good n-tier application I would suggest you quickly read http://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-Enterprise-NET-Wrox-Programmer/dp/0470447613

Really, it all depends on your requirements. I would generally have my WCF project separate from the ASP.NET project so that 'heavy' processing tasks can be passed to the WCF and not degrade the websites performance.

n-tier has been the de-facto design for years, but for smaller projects people are arguing that EF + n-tier etc, is overkill and that micro-frameworks like NancyFx and Simple.Data are more appropriate. It all depends on what you are actually building.

Or are you asking how to get started with Linq?
Mannings "Link in Action" is very good. As are the webcasts on http://shop.tekpub.com/products/linq

Answer (score 0):

The client and the service should be in different projects if there is a need for distribution. I would generally go with a presentation layer project(web app) and a different project for DAL. But then this segregation depends on the strategic vision of your project. Do you have solid reasons to believe that once you develop this code, there would be no need for extensibility?If that's the case then have your DAL and Webapp in the same project. Else separate it out. Entity framework provides better support for testability and its the roadmap and it integrates well with WCF as compared to Linq to SQL

Comment: to make it more clear , my project has three main aspects, a web app, service and client app. WebApp will be hosted on someserver. On the same server, i would like to deploy the service. Webapp has nothing to do with the service. It will directly interact with the database.  On the other hand, the service has permission for selecting records from the database, not Insert, delete and update. Client app will be scattered to different location. It might be a winapp, wince app ,android app or java app. and it will interact with the service to fetch data only. Thats my plan.